# Background required for coursera complex analysis course

Tags: complex-analysis, self-learning

I am currently attempting to do [complex analysis course on coursera](https://www.coursera.org/course/complexanalysis) , the syllabus is also on that page.
I am college freshman who hasn't taken calculus yet, although I've taken Linear and Abstract algebra.
My question is that if its possible to do that course with my current background or should I try again after taking calculus.

Comment: Excuse the question: what is "coursera", anyway?

Comment: I think you **must** first take calculus, and the most of it the better.

Comment: @DonAntonio its a site that offers free online courses for the masses https://www.coursera.org/

Comment: Oh, I see @Surya. Thanks.

Comment: *this is the syllabus* **Note:** Your link leads to a log-in page, not to the syllabus, at least on my computer, and my computer is more important than your computer regarding whether I can answer your question.

Comment: I have edited your question, and hopefully solved the link issue. Please edit again, if what I have done is not correct.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro sorry I hadn't realized it was behind login wall. I am not sure if I am allowed to copy/paste syllabus here.

Comment: I suggest not copying/pasting. As for complex analysis, if the coverage includes the Cauchy-Riemann equations and contour integrals, the answer is easy: **NO** However, there are many topics involving complex numbers that you can study now: **1.** [Chapter 5: Complex Numbers](http://www.numbertheory.org/book/cha5.pdf) in **Elementary Linear Algebra** by Keith Matthews. **2.** [**Introduction to the Geometry of Complex Numbers**](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0486466299) by Roland Deaux. **3.** [*Conformal Mappings*](http://mcs.cankaya.edu.tr/proje/2010/guz/mustafaakman/rapor.pdf) by Mustafa Akman.

Answer (score 1):

You need through multivariable calculus without doubt. And some real analysis (understanding uniform convergence) is highly recommended. BTW, we can't easily access your links.